# We expected to find the global Cypress in the parent window but it is missing! error in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am getting this error:

```
document.domain = 'myappdomain.com'; 
var Cypress = window.Cypress = parent.Cypress; 
if (!Cypress) { throw new Error('Something went terribly wrong and we cannot proceed. We expected to find the global Cypress in the parent window but it is missing!. This should never happen and likely is a bug. Please open an issue!'); }; 
Cypress.action('app:window:before:load', window);
```

I don't know what is cause of this error, same used to work before and I don't know what has changed in our react app + cypress 3.4.1 and we use okta for oauth, please suggest how to debug and fix this issue?

attached cypress log for the same in Github issues [https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/972#issuecomment-557894206]

Answer (score 1):

I have faced with the same problem. I have fixed it by clearing the application data in chrome developer tools ( **chrome dev tools -> Application -> Clear storage -> push the "Clear site data" button** ).
I hope it will help you too.